# Can lustful desires be expressed appropriately?

Tags: sexuality

Can lustful desires be expressed in a kosher way? I would like some clarity on this issue.

Comment: These are huge and important issues! You would do well to post 3 or 4 of them as different questions so they can get the proper answers they deserve!

Comment: This question needs explanation. How do the first three sentences lead to, "_Therefore, is lust considered avodah zara?" Doesn't follow at all. Then a follow-up, "If so then why?" Huh? What were you asking if you didn't know why?

Comment: The following source may help turn this into a sensible question - or answer it: https://www.sefaria.org/Niddah.13a.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en "It [wasting seed] is considered as though he worships idols"

Comment: very relevant gemara regarding lust within marriage: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.62a.3?lang=bi

Answer (score 1):

Sexuality and sexual passion can promote and actualize a man's or woman's innate Divine potential as nothing else can, but the fascination with its very power can divert a person's focus from its true purpose and cause him to focus instead on the ecstatic experience itself.

Man is intended to engage in sexual pleasure as a spiritual pursuit that gives pleasure to his wife, makes him into a more holy person, and increases the Divine Image on earth (ideally by resulting in children).

Source: https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/379917/jewish/Propriety-and-Passion.htm

Comment: While you have put a good deal of time and effort into this well thought -out answer, Mi Yodeya isn't necessarily the right place for a long form screed of this kind.